# React js communication between parent and child component using props send data from shop to prod details component

Tags: reactjs

This is a shop Component which is the parent component in which I have an image on click handler in which I need to send data to a child component called Prod Details.

And the click event is detailMovie so need to pass it to child using props

The child component should should display the selected data from the function

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import { ProdDetails } from "./ProductDetails";
// import ProductsJSON from "../data/products.json";

export class Shop extends React.Component {
  // to route to details page from list
  onNavigateProdDetails() {
    browserHistory.push("/proddetails");
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      selectedData: {}
    };
  }

  //API Call to fetch data
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findresponse => {
        console.log(findresponse.movies);
        this.setState({
          data: findresponse.movies
        });
      });
  }
  detailMovie(moviedata) {
    //this.props.clickedItem = moviedata;
    this.selectedMovieList = moviedata;
  };

  render() {
    // find the clicked item and local storage
    let selectedMovie;
    

    return (
      <div className="shop pad-30">
        <h1>Latest Arrivals</h1>
        <div className="shop-inner">
          <div className="prods-wrap">
            {this.state.data.map((moviedata, i) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={moviedata.id}
                  onClick={() => this.detailMovie(moviedata)}
                  data-key={moviedata.id}
                  className="shop-inner-each"
                >
                  <Link to="/proddetails">
                    <div className="shop-inner-each-img">
                      <img src={moviedata.image} className="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                  <div className="shop-inner-each-details">
                    <div className="shop-inner-each-details-left">
                      <Link to="/proddetails">
                        <h3>{moviedata.title}</h3>
                      </Link>
                      <p>$ {moviedata.releaseYear}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="shop-inner-each-details-right">
                      <button type="button" className="fi flaticon-like" />
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="fi flaticon-shopping-cart"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { browserHistory, Link } from "react-router";

export class ProdDetails extends React.Component {
  onNavigateShop() {
    browserHistory.push("/shop");
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // copy current list of items
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="proddetails">
        <div className="proddetails-left">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div className="proddetails-right">
          <div className="proddetails-right-inner">
            <Link to="/shop" className="btn btn-pagination">
              <i className="fi flaticon-left-arrow" /> Back
            </Link>
            {/* <h2>{this.props.movieData.title}</h2>
            <h3>$ {this.props.movieData.releaseYear}</h3> */}
            {/* <p>{this.updatedItem.description}</p> */}
            <div className="actions">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-prime">
                <i className="fi flaticon-like" /> Add to Wishlist
              </button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-prime">
                <i className="fi flaticon-shopping-cart" /> Add to Cart
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And right now what is happening? What do you expect to happen ?

Comment: so right now if i use <ProdDetails this.props.data={this.selectedMovieList }></ProdDetails> in Shop and use props i am not able to get the props data in ProdDetails componet can u please help me out how to send the data to child component

Comment: You're not using it correctly. It should be `<ProdDetails data={this.selectedMovieList }></ProdDetails>` The way you used it, it will be available on `this.props.this.props.data`

Comment: why this.props.this.props.data ?

Comment: <ProdDetails data={this.selectedMovieList}></ProdDetails> i am using like this in Shop Component is it correct

Comment: In prod details using like this   <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
            <h3>$ {this.props.data.releaseYear}</h3>